# kubectl patch deployment date return error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

When I try

`kubectl patch deployment my-node-app -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"`date
+'%s'`\"}}}}}" -n my-namespace`

I get below error:

`The Deployment "my-node-app" is invalid: spec.template.labels: Invalid value: "`date +'%s'`": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')`

What am I missing in my code ?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: my-node-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-node-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-node-app
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: node
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: gcr.io/my-repo/my-node-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: my-configmap
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 8Gi
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: kubectl get deployments -n namespace shows me the deployment

Comment: is there a way to patch my deployment with this configuration ?

Comment: I'd typically recommend editing the YAML file you show here, committing the result to source control, and re-running `kubectl apply -f`.  If you're just trying to make an artificial change to get the deployment to restart, `kubectl rollout restart deployment -n dev node` will do it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this label ? do you want to print the DD_MM_YYY as value to the date key ? Could you provide the expected outcome.

You are getting error because your value doesn't pass the regex mentioned which is used by k8s to check valid values.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using a trigger to build my Docker image with the tag latest. With a kubectl patch, I  want to pull again the new image via terminal without using a CD tool. How can I add the correct line for the date?

Comment: You should probably use a unique tag for each build and change the `image:` line.  That will make it possible to roll back, you'll be able to easily tell what build each pod is running, and it won't force the cluster to do a no-op pull if nothing has changed (you can remove the `imagePullPolicy:` line).

Comment: Why would you want to use the date? What's the usecase here? What's the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to echo your json string:

```
echo "{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"date":"date +'%s'"}}}}}"
-> {spec:{template:{metadata:{labels:{date:date +%s}}}}}
```

In your case, you want to execute the date command, so :

```
echo "{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"date":"$(date +'%s')"}}}}}"
-> {spec:{template:{metadata:{labels:{date:1594299081}}}}}
```

even better, you should wrap the json string in simple quotes:

```
echo '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"date":"'$(date +'%s')'"}}}}}'
-> {"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"date":"1594299282"}}}}}
```

Also, you don't really need quotes for `date +%s`

Comment: I'm using a trigger to build my Docker image with the tag latest. With a kubectl patch, I want to pull again the new image via terminal without using a CD tool. How can I add the correct line for the date in the YAML? your solutions don't work. I have  the same error